# Native JS alternative for Java's next() and hasNext() methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, textarea, cross-reference

So recently I built a search and replace program with Java, now I am working on translating/rebuilding that program with JavaScript. However, I am having trouble finding JS method alternatives for next() and hasNext(). I am new to JS so I don't know what JS methods would work similarly to the Java methods I am used to.

This is my program, I commented through it to show exactly what I am doing with the previously mentioned methods. Basic set up, 2 text areas, one for the search box (search criteria, box 2), and one for the main document (the field of search, box 1). It basically boils down to a cross-reference. It will highlight all the similarities between the documents.

```
function search() {
    //define an array to store  the search criteria.
    var array = [];
    // define a counter.
    var n = 0;
    // define a constant for the first box, the search field.
    const box1 = document.getElementById("box1"); 
    // define a constant for the second box, the search criteria.
    const box2 = document.getElementById("box2"); 
    // loop through the search criteria, storing each word as a seperate element in the array.
    // this uses non js terms, this is where I need the help.
    while (box2.hasNext()) {
        array[n] = box2.next();
        n = n + 1;
    }
    // resets the counter.
    n = 0;
    // loops through each search item, finding and replacing each item with itself, surrounded by mark tags. 
    while (n <= array.length) {
        box1.replace(array[n], "<mark>" + array[n] + "</mark>");    
    }

    }
</script>
```

There is bound to be other issues, bugs and syntax, feel free to point them out but lets try and keep the focus on the methodology (i.e. method alternatives for next() and hasNext()).

Thanks.

-EDIT- I'd prefer to use native alternative (no jquery) becuase I know even less about jquery than I do js.

Comment: `box2` is a dom  element. What are you expecting `box2.hasnext()` or `box2.next()` to do exactly? And based on `box1.replace()` I believe you want both box variables to be `value` of their respective elements...not the element themselves

Comment: To get words array from input element just do `var wordsArray = inputElement.value.split(" ")`

Comment: What it would do if this were plain java, box2.hasNext() would continue the loop until there where no more words in the string. box2.next() would refer specifically to the next word in the string. In java, it deliminates between spaces. So if I said var str = "The quick brown fox", next() would equal "The"

Comment: Ok no such string iterators in javascript. Aim for array and work with array methods. And a while loop like that would create infinite loop

Comment: MDN docs are excellent for javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Not infinite, as eventually the document would come to the last word, and then conclude. Ill look into the split(), so far that may solve half my issue.